# How are batteries affected on planes?

Tags: energy, charge, potential-energy, batteries

I'm currently an engineer and was fascinated at how technology came to be and how we were able to find out that we can take energy and essentially store it for a later time. I was thinking about batteries and how they exactly store energy.

The first question I have is how exactly do batteries store energy for a long time?
and since your altitude increases when you are on a plane, I assume a battery gains potential energy. So does it actually charge the battery? A following question is if that is the reason why batteries can explode at a higher altitude?

Comment: Do you feel more more energized on a plane? Do your electronics become fully charged on a plane?

Comment: Oh I see. Didnt think of it that way. But would there be potential to use potential energy and convert it so that it would charge?

Comment: This might be a better question for engineering se

Comment: If you took some water up on the plane, then poured it down through a water wheel attached to a generator, you could generate some electrical energy that way.

Comment: https://www.foxtrot.com/2018/10/07/energy-boost/

Comment: Have you tried thinking about how energy would be conserved if the battery gets charged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batteries of the sort you mention create electrical power through chemical reactions occurring inside them. Those chemical reactions are not linked in any way to the height above the earth that the plane is flying at- which instead establishes what the gravitational potential energy of the battery (and any other massive object) is.

That said, gravitational potential energy is converted into electrical power all the time, at hydroelectric plants, by means that have nothing to do with electrochemistry.